# How to avoid blank space in staggerd grid view when we scroll move top to bottom

Tags: android, staggered-gridview

i am new to develop staggered grid view . i have a problem in staggered grid view. when we scroll from top to bottom it is scrolled. but again go to  bottom to top grid view start image is bank. i am sending screen short for that.. thanks advance. 
[image]

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        boolforprogressdialogmyfeed=true;
        BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(getApplicationContext(), "ab5c30f1 ");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activitynewstagredgridview);

        mystream=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mystream);
        featured=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.featured);
        all=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.popular);
        search=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.search);

        mystream_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mystream_text);
        featured_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.featured_text);
        popular_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.popular_text);

        mystream.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_tab_left);
        featured.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3a404c"));
        all.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        mystream_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BFC9CB"));
        featured_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BFC9CB"));
        popular_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3a404c"));

        mystream.setOnClickListener(this);
        featured.setOnClickListener(this);
        all.setOnClickListener(this);
        search.setOnClickListener(this);


        ptrstaggredview=(PullToRefreshStaggeredGridView)findViewById(R.id.staggeredGridView1);
        ptrstaggredview.setMode(PullToRefreshBase.Mode.PULL_FROM_START);
        popular_Adapter = new ImageBOStaggredAdapter(getParent(),mystreamList.size(),parent, mystreamList);


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_loading_footer, null);

            ptrstaggredview.getRefreshableView().setFooterView(footerView);
            ptrstaggredview.setAdapter(popular_Adapter);


          strcurrenttab="all";

          new Load(intstartValue).execute();
          popular_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        ptrstaggredview.setOnLoadmoreListener(new StaggeredGridView.OnLoadmoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadmore() {

                 //ptrstaggredview.SMOOTH_SCROLL_LONG_DURATION_MS=BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY;
                //dialog=MyProgressDialog.show(getParent(),null,null);

                 intstartValue=intstartValue+10;
                 new Load(intstartValue).execute();


                //  

            }
        });

        /*ObjectAnimator animator=ObjectAnimator.ofInt(yourHorizontalScrollView, "scrollX",targetXScroll );
        animator.start();*/
        ptrstaggredview.setOnRefreshListener(new PullToRefreshBase.OnRefreshListener<StaggeredGridView>() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<StaggeredGridView> refreshView) {


                    boolpulltorefresh=true;
                    intstartValue=0;
//                  if(strcurrenttab.equals("mys"))
                    new Load(intstartValue).execute();
                    popular_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  ptrstaggredview.onRefreshComplete();
                }
            });


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==mystream){
            Log.e("onclick for mystream","onclick mystream");

            strcurrenttab="mystream"; boolforprogressdialogmyfeed=true;
//          ptrstaggredview.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            intstartValue=0;
            mystream.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            featured.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3a404c"));
            all.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_tab_right);
            mystream_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3a404c"));
            featured_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BFC9CB"));
            popular_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BFC9CB"));
            ptrstaggredview.setMode(PullToRefreshBase.Mode.PULL_FROM_START);
             mystreamList.clear();
              ImageBOStaggredAdapter.views.clear();
             new Load(intstartValue).execute();
              popular_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              popular_Adapter = new ImageBOStaggredAdapter(getParent(),mystreamList.size(),parent, mystreamList);
//
//         
//              LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//              footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_loading_footer, null);
//              ptrstaggredview.getRefreshableView().setFooterView(footerView);
                ptrstaggredview.setAdapter(popular_Adapter);



        }else if(v==featured){
            Log.e("onclick for featured","onclick featured");
            strcurrenttab="featured"; boolforprogressdialogmyfeed=true;
            intstartValue=0;
            mystream.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_tab_left);
            featured.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            all.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_tab_right);



            mystream_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BFC9CB"));
            featured_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3a404c"));
            popular_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BFC9CB"));

             ptrstaggredview.setMode(PullToRefreshBase.Mode.PULL_FROM_START);
             mystreamList.clear();
              ImageBOStaggredAdapter.views.clear();
             new Load(intstartValue).execute();
              popular_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              popular_Adapter = new ImageBOStaggredAdapter(getParent(),mystreamList.size(),parent, mystreamList);
//
//         
//              LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//              footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_loading_footer, null);
//              ptrstaggredview.getRefreshableView().setFooterView(footerView);
                ptrstaggredview.setAdapter(popular_Adapter);




        }else if(v==all){
            Log.e("onclick for all","onclick all");

            strcurrenttab="all"; boolforprogressdialogmyfeed=true;
            intstartValue=0; 
//          ptrstaggredview.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            mystream.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_tab_left);
            featured.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3a404c"));
            all.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            mystream_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BFC9CB"));
            featured_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BFC9CB"));
            popular_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3a404c"));


            ptrstaggredview.setMode(PullToRefreshBase.Mode.PULL_FROM_START);

               mystreamList.clear();ImageBOStaggredAdapter.views.clear();
               new Load(intstartValue).execute();
              popular_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              popular_Adapter = new ImageBOStaggredAdapter(getParent(),mystreamList.size(),parent, mystreamList);
//
//            
//              LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//              footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_loading_footer, null);
//              ptrstaggredview.getRefreshableView().setFooterView(footerView);
                ptrstaggredview.setAdapter(popular_Adapter);


        }else if(v==search)
        {



            // here is the codr for intigrating tabs,..
//          Log.e("userrrrrr",""+Logined_User.getId());
            View vi =TabActivityActivity.group.getLocalActivityManager()  
                       .startActivity("Items", new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SearchActivity.class)
//                     .putExtra("imageBo", ""+gson.toJson(imagesBO)) 
                       .putExtra("parent", "Activity")
                       .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))  
                       .getDecorView();  

                   TabActivityActivity.group.replaceView(vi);


        }

    }

    class Load extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>
     {
        /*MyProgressDialog dialog;
        JSONObject jobjectsee=null;JSONArray jarray=null;
       String jsonresult="";
        */
//      Log.e("current before webservice","current time service time"+);

        MyProgressDialog dialog;
        int strat;
        public Load(int strat) {
            super();
            this.strat = strat;
        }
        String strjsonresult="";

      protected void onPreExecute() 
      {

          if(boolforprogressdialogmyfeed==true){
              dialog=MyProgressDialog.show(getParent(), null, null);
              dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 

              footerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            ptrstaggredview.getRefreshableView().re
//            ptrstaggredview.h
          }else{

          footerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          }

      }
      @Override
      protected Long doInBackground(URL... arg0) {

    try {

        if(strcurrenttab.equals("mystream")){
              Log.e("onpost execute"," on doin of the mystream"); 
//      Log.e("url is...",""+DataUrl.getHomePageByUSer(LogindUser.getUser().getUserId(), strat));


//      strjsonresult=Netcon.getValuefromUrl(DataUrl.getHomePageByUSer(LogindUser.getUser().getUserId(), strat));

        strjsonresult=Netcon.getValuefromUrl("http://166.78.178.47:8080/json/pinboard?userMystream.userID="+LogindUser.getUser().getUserId()+"&userMystream.start="+strat);
           Log.e(" mystream response is ","<><><><<>"+"http://166.78.178.47:8080/json/pinboard?userMystream.userID="+LogindUser.getUser().getUserId()+"&userMystream.start="+strat);

        }else if(strcurrenttab.equals("featured"))
        {
              Log.e("onpost execute"," on do in  execut of the featured"); 
            Log.e("url is...",""+DataUrl.getFeaturedImages(strat, LogindUser.getUser().getUserId()));
//          featuredList_temp.clear();
            strjsonresult=Netcon.getValuefromUrl(DataUrl.getFeaturedImages(strat, LogindUser.getUser().getUserId()));
        }else   if(strcurrenttab.equals("all"))
        {
              Log.e("onpost execute"," on doinback execut of the all"); 
            Log.e("url is...",""+DataUrl.getHomePageByCategory(strat, 0, LogindUser.getUser().getUserId()));
//          popularList_temp.clear();
            strjsonresult=Netcon.getValuefromUrl(DataUrl.getHomePageByCategory(strat, 0, LogindUser.getUser().getUserId()));
        }

        //this for pulltorefresh
         if(boolpulltorefresh==true){
             mystreamList.clear();
            ImageBOStaggredAdapter.views.clear();
               boolpulltorefresh=false;
           }

        }  catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

       }


       return null;
      }

      @SuppressLint("NewApi")
      protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {



          new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                getParent().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            //calling();



          try {

              if(boolforprogressdialogmyfeed==true){
                  boolforprogressdialogmyfeed=false;
                  try{
                  dialog.dismiss();
                  }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}


              }


              if(strcurrenttab.equals("mystream")){
                  Log.e("onpost execute"," on post execut of the mystream"); 

                /*JSONObject object = new JSONObject(strjsonresult);
                if(object.getBoolean("statusFlag"))
                {
                    JSONArray array= object.getJSONArray("homePageImages");
                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)

                    {

                        ImagesBO imagesBO = new ImagesBO();
                        imagesBO= gson.fromJson(array.getJSONObject(i).toString(), ImagesBO.class);
//                      mystreamList.add(imagesBO);  // commented by Ramesh for endlesscroll 
                        mystreamList.add(imagesBO);

//                       popular_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                }*/
                  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strjsonresult);
                     JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("images");

                     Log.e("Array size is","<>"+array.length());
                     for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
                     {
                      ImagesBO imagesBO = new ImagesBO();
                      imagesBO= gson.fromJson(array.getJSONObject(i).toString(), ImagesBO.class);
                      mystreamList.add(imagesBO);
//                    popularList.add(imagesBO);  // added by Ramesh for endlessscroll
//                    Log.e("userid is","<><>"+imagesBO.getUserId()+imagesBO.getUsername());
                     }


                }else if(strcurrenttab.equals("featured")){
                    Log.e("onpost execute"," on post execut of the featured");
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(strjsonresult);
                    JSONArray array= object.getJSONArray("featuredImages");
                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
                    {
                        ImagesBO imagesBO = new ImagesBO();
                        imagesBO= gson.fromJson(array.getJSONObject(i).toString(), ImagesBO.class);
//                      featuredList.add(imagesBO);
                        mystreamList.add(imagesBO);  // added by Ramesh for endlessscroll
//                       popular_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }else if(strcurrenttab.equals("all")){

                    Log.e("onpost execute"," on post execut of the all");






                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strjsonresult);
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("homePageImages");


                        Log.e("Array size is","<>"+array.length());
                        for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
                        {
                            ImagesBO imagesBO = new ImagesBO();

                            imagesBO= gson.fromJson(array.getJSONObject(i).toString(), ImagesBO.class);
//                          popularList.add(imagesBO);  // added by Ramesh for endlessscroll
                            mystreamList.add(imagesBO);
//                           popular_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                          views_popular.add(popularimagelist);
                        }




                }


              popular_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


              Log.e("Sizeee","<>"+mystreamList.size());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //

            }
           });


               // dialog.dismiss();
                }


            }, 20000);
```

Comment: did you got your answer?

Comment: Have you solved this issue

Comment: have you got any solution

Answer (score 0):

Set some minimum height `android:minHeight="100dp"` for your ImageView in the adapter xml.

Comment: i have the same issue using Etsy staggeredGridveiw plugin